# Error while posting a request via soap client

Tags: php

I have implemented arzoo Flight API in my php web site.
I have used soap client to send the request. while browsing I got the following error

```
HERE IS A FAULT : SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /home/wwwkomet/public_html/demo1/dom_avail.php:71 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('getAvailability', Array) #2 {main}
```

This is my code

```
$location_URL = "http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability";
$action_URL ="http://com.arzoo.flight.avail";

$client = new SoapClient('http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl', array(
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
'location' => $location_URL,
'uri'      => $action_URL,
'style'    => SOAP_RPC,
'use'      => SOAP_ENCODED,
'trace'    => 1,
));

try
{
    $result = $client->__call('getAvailability',array($req_int));
    $response= htmlentities($result);
}
```

What is the reason to this? How to overcome this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/ giving HTTP status 404

Comment: but http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability is available

Comment: try it to check var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());

Comment: 59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability taking too much time to response...Still till commenting time the url is did not give any response

Answer (score 0):

I just working on the same Arzoo Flight search API, Your code just worked for me Where as i just added `catch` to the above code:

```
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

For the response to be print u just use:

> var_dump($response);